# Write a program to create a formula matching input set to output set

Tags: function, obfuscation, theory, brute-force

I just saw on StackOverflow an explanation of Obfuscated C explanation. I find the contest very interesting as I get to learn new C, and moreover new programming knowledge everyday with it.

One interesting one is [Explain 1-liner party of a US President from IOCCC 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109006/explain-1-liner-party-of-a-us-president-from-ioccc-2013)

As you can see, the program uses a series of modulo functions (ie. (integer)%4796%275%4 ) to hash an input number to form one of two output numbers. This "hash" function had been trialed and errored to work correctly for a limited set of inputs.

I think this would be a great thing to have to minimize the size of your programs so you can map one result to another. For example, you can have {apple, lettuce, carrot, pear, orange, asparagus} when converted to a number and passed through the function, turn into {1,0,0,1,1,0} and this function takes less space than a full database to search a string and ascertain its fruit-ness.

So my question is... how do you go about creating a program to brute-force stacked modulo functions that will work for all a given input set and output set?

Continuing the fruit example, you can convert the first two letters of the fruits into a number like so:
apple -> ap -> 0x6170

so the list becomes {0x6170, 0x6c65, 0x6361, 0x7065, 0x6f72, 0x6173}

So you want generate a function comprising of repeated modulos to map {0x6170, 0x6c65, 0x6361, 0x7065, 0x6f72, 0x6173} to {1,0,0,1,1,0}

How would one go about doing so?

Comment: It sounds like you get that brute force is the concept. I don't think there's any particular clever way of going about it, you're question is just a complicated way of asking if the Halting Problem has a solution.

Comment: I just found this question http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/249458/given-known-inputs-and-outputs-can-we-generate-candidate-functions-that-will-ma

Comment: What does this have to do with databases, or C for that matter?

Comment: It's a similar question but the difference between mine and that one is that there is a constraint on what type of function to use. Moreover, you can specify a constant how many stacks of modulos to use.

Comment: It can be used to create a database.

Comment: I have edited the tags to pertain more to topic. I believe it is a theoretical computer science concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting challenge, but way beyond my mathematical skills. So, here is a brute force implementation in plain C `:P`

I don't have a mathematical proof and so cannot prove this will *always* find a solution, but it works for your input. Adding the 'fruit' "clinton" and 'vegetable' "mccaine" make it run for a bit longer; adding "apricot" will signal a clash! (Which is reported but doesn't say where. Note that a clash inside *similar* items -- fruits *or* vegetables -- should actually be allowed. I did not write the code for that, but it should be relatively simple.)

To see a longer sequence, add "banana". For some reason, this needs to go up to `163,13,2`. Funny enough, then adding "kumquat" (I'm running out of fruits) doesn't take much longer, and even with another "coconut" it doesn't take much more time.

Implementation notes:

You can limit the search to the maximum input 2-byte code, because the `mod` function will never do anything with larger numbers. For consistency, this C code starts with testing all 1-mod values (although I did not find anything useful). Then it tests 2-mod values, and finally 3-mod values. If it does not find a value, you could extend it to look for 4-mod and 5-mod long sequences, but the search time will increase logarithmically (!).

It should be possible to categorize on more than 2 values; that needs very minor rewriting of the code. I suspect looking for a match for all will then take much longer.

It should also be possible to return other 'indexes' than `0` and `1`; as I'm writing this, the rest of the CPU is working hard on `2` and `0`. It seems that's going to take quite a bit of time, though.

C implementation, brute force:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
  char *fruits[] = { "apple", "pear", "orange"} ; //, "clinton"  };
  char *veggies[] = { "lettuce", "carrot", "asparagus" }; // , "mccaine" };
  int num_f, num_v, found_match;
  unsigned short *code[2], max_code = 0;

  int i,j, mod_value1, mod_value2, mod_value3;

  num_f = sizeof(fruits)/sizeof(fruits[0]);
  num_v = sizeof(veggies)/sizeof(veggies[0]);

  code[0] = malloc((num_f+num_v)*sizeof(short));
  code[1] = malloc((num_f+num_v)*sizeof(short));

  for (i=0; i<num_f; i++)
  {
    code[0][i] = (fruits[i][0]<<8)+fruits[i][1];
    code[1][i] = 1;
    if (code[0][i] > max_code)
      max_code = code[0][i];
  }
  for (i=0; i<num_v; i++)
  {
    code[0][num_f+i] = (veggies[i][0]<<8)+veggies[i][1];
    code[1][num_f+i] = 0;
    if (code[0][num_f+i] > max_code)
      max_code = code[0][num_f+i];
  }

  for (i=0; i<num_f+num_v; i++)
  {
    for (j=i+1; j<num_f+num_v; j++)
    {
      if (code[0][i] == code[0][j])
      {
        printf ("clash!\n");
        exit(-1);
      }
    }
  }

  printf ("calculating...\n");
  for (mod_value1=1; mod_value1<max_code; mod_value1++)
  {
    found_match = 1;
    for (i=0; i<num_f+num_v; i++)
    {
      if (code[0][i] % mod_value1 != code[1][i])
      {
        found_match = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (found_match)
    {
      printf ("mod %d should work\n", mod_value1);
      break;
    }
  }
  if (found_match)
  {
    for (i=0; i<num_f; i++)
    {
      printf ("%s -> %d\n", fruits[i], code[0][i]  % mod_value2 % mod_value1);
    }
    for (i=0; i<num_v; i++)
    {
      printf ("%s -> %d\n", veggies[i], code[0][num_f+i]  % mod_value2 % mod_value1);
    }
  } else
  {
  for (mod_value1=1; mod_value1<max_code; mod_value1++)
  {
    for (mod_value2=mod_value1+1; mod_value2<max_code; mod_value2++)
    {
      found_match = 1;
      for (i=0; i<num_f+num_v; i++)
      {
        if (code[0][i] % mod_value2 % mod_value1 != code[1][i])
        {
          found_match = 0;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (found_match)
      {
        printf ("mod %d mod %d should work\n", mod_value2, mod_value1);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (found_match)
      break;
  }

  if (found_match)
  {
    for (i=0; i<num_f; i++)
    {
      printf ("%s -> %d\n", fruits[i], code[0][i]  % mod_value2 % mod_value1);
    }
    for (i=0; i<num_v; i++)
    {
      printf ("%s -> %d\n", veggies[i], code[0][num_f+i]  % mod_value2 % mod_value1);
    }
  } else
  {
    for (mod_value1=1; mod_value1<max_code; mod_value1++)
    {
      for (mod_value2=mod_value1+1; mod_value2<max_code; mod_value2++)
      {
        for (mod_value3=mod_value2+1; mod_value3<max_code; mod_value3++)
        {
          found_match = 1;
          for (i=0; i<num_f+num_v; i++)
          {
            if (code[0][i] % mod_value3 % mod_value2 % mod_value1 != code[1][i])
            {
              found_match = 0;
              break;
            }
          }
          if (found_match)
          {
            printf ("mod %d mod %d mod %d should work\n", mod_value3, mod_value2, mod_value1);
            break;
          }
        }
        if (found_match)
          break;
      }
      if (found_match)
        break;
    }

    if (found_match)
    {
      for (i=0; i<num_f; i++)
      {
        printf ("%s -> %d\n", fruits[i], code[0][i] % mod_value3 % mod_value2 % mod_value1);
      }
      for (i=0; i<num_v; i++)
      {
        printf ("%s -> %d\n", veggies[i], code[0][num_f+i] % mod_value3 % mod_value2 % mod_value1);
      }
    }
  }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Result for your original 3 fruit, 3 veggie list:

```
mod 25 mod 2 should work
apple -> 1
pear -> 1
orange -> 1
lettuce -> 0
carrot -> 0
asparagus -> 0
```

Late Result, for a wanted output of `2` and `0`:

```
mod 507 mod 8 mod 3 should work
apple -> 2
pear -> 2
orange -> 2
lettuce -> 0
carrot -> 0
asparagus -> 0
```

Later result yet, with the 'disputable' "tomato" added as a Category 2:

```
mod 103 mod 7 mod 3 should work
apple -> 1
pear -> 1
orange -> 1
lettuce -> 0
carrot -> 0
asparagus -> 0
tomato -> 2
```

Comment: It is very helpful!! Thank you! I had fun analyzing what your code does. Really cool implementation.